# Capturing face frames in python

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I'm new in python. I'm using python 3.5, and openCV3. I have the following code which is suppose to capture around 20 frames through the webcam:

---

```
import cv2
import time
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cam.isOpened())
detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

Id=1 
sampleNum=0

time.sleep(5)
while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

        #incrementing sample number 
        sampleNum=sampleNum+1
        #saving the captured face in the dataset folder
        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    #wait for 100 miliseconds 
    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    # break if the sample number is morethan 20
    elif sampleNum>20:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

However I'm getting this error:

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: ......\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor

How can I overcome such error please?

Comment: what is the output of print(cam.isOpened()) ?

Comment: I just double check if the cam is working or not. However my above code failedto capture my photo and save it in a dataset folder!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked on my machine and tracks my face. Try the following:

- make sure the haarcascade xml file is in the same directory as where you run the code. You can also specify the absolute path to the file to be sure.
- check if the `gray` image looks like what you expect `cv2.imgshow('gray', gray)` (and insert a sleep so you can see it). The cam.isOpened() should return True
- check if its datatype is an uint8 np.ndarray: `print(gray.dtype)`

Comment: May I now what version of python are you using?? 3.5? Or less?

Comment: Also, do you mean that I have to change this line from  cv2.imshow('frame', img) to  cv2.imshow('gray', gray) !!! Also, I have tried to specify the absolute path of the xml bu it didn't work!

Comment: File "C:/Users/Mary/Desktop/Project/face Rec/face_datasets.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor

Comment: I used Python3. The imshow method just displays the image on your screen. Can you see it?

Comment: I can't capture any image or see it. Could it be something related to my setting environment?

Comment: This is why debugging is important. Basically, the only code needed to find something wrong are the first three lines. You might be specifying the wrong device (camera). See the videocapture [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html). If you want to use a pre-recorded video file, you can also specify the path to that file.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the camera. I solved it by putting -1 and run the code. Then again change -1 to -0 and run it again. Lastly, change -0 to 0 and run the code. By following those steps I were able to run the code correctly. But I couldn't understand the reasons!!!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Something else must have changed, otherwise it should still have failed. It's probably a good idea to figure out what fixed the problem so that you don't forget in the future and can help others who have the same problem.